# Trouble to set coordinates in OpenLayers when using Long and Lat from GoogleMaps

Tags: google-maps, openstreetmap, openlayers-3

Here is the coordinates of Tehran on Google Maps.
https://www.google.com/maps/place/Tehran/@35.6964895,51.0696315,10z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m2!3m1!1s0x3f8e00491ff3dcd9:0xf0b3697c567024bc

```
35.6961° N, 51.4231° E
```

I'm trying to find this coordinate in OpenLayers but I had no luck, here is my code:

```
map = new ol.Map({
    target: 'sample-map',
    layers: [
        new ol.layer.Tile({
            source: new ol.source.OSM()
        })
    ],
    view: new ol.View({         
        center:  [35.6961, 51.4231],
        zoom: 4
    })
});
```

I'm also trying to get current coordinates in degrees but I don't know how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what is the problem, but I can say this: you need to swap your parameters on `center` to `[51.4231, 35.6961]`.

According to the [Openlayers documentation](http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Map-js.html#OpenLayers.Map.center) the `center` is in the format `[x-axis, y-axis]` or in your case `[East, North]`.

In your specific case your source projection is NOT lat/long so you have to convert. The following code should work for you:

`map = new ol.Map({
    target: 'sample-map',
    layers: [ new ol.layer.Tile({
            source: new ol.source.OSM()
        })],
    view: new ol.View({

        center:  ol.proj.transform([51.4231, 35.6961], 'EPSG:4326', new ol.source.OSM().getProjection()),
        zoom: 10
    })
});`

Comment: How could I convert from East-North to x/y-axis or wise-versa?

Comment: I have added the code you need in order to convert.